# Proper way to solve this angular vs. linear speed calculation?

Tags: calculus, rotations

radius = 20 in.
Linear speed = V = $15 \frac{miles}{hour}$

How many revolutions per minute is the wheel spinning?

W = angluar speed (in radians)

$V = rW$

$15 \frac{miles}{hour} = (20 in.)(W)$

How do you do the next step to solve for W ?

$$W = \frac{15 \frac{miles}{hour}}{20 in.}$$

Not sure the easiest way to simplify this.

If I convert 20 in. to .000315 miles, how is the result of dividing $15 \frac{mile}{hour}$ by .000315 miles ?  Namely, what units are left when you divide $\frac{miles}{hour}$ by miles?

I ended up with:

$$W = \frac{15 \frac{miles}{hour}}{20 in.}=.75\frac{miles}{hour*in.}(\frac{1 hour}{60 mins})(\frac{1 rev}{2\pi rad})(\frac{12 in}{1 ft})(\frac{5280 ft}{1 mile}) = \frac{(.75)(12)(5280)}{(60)(2\pi)} \frac{revs}{mins}=126 \frac{revs}{mins}$$

Comment: Convert miles to inches and hours to seconds to get the result.

Comment: Do I do it before the algebraic division?   I am confused by the division of units.

Comment: The order wouldn't matter. If you do the algebraic division first, you will get $0.75$ miles /(hour x inches). Converting miles to inches will remove distance units from the units and converting hours to seconds will give the answer in radians. 15 miles/hour divided by 0.000315 miles will be $\frac{15}{0.000315}\hour, the units can cancel out.

Comment: If I convert 20 in. to .000315 miles, how is the result of dividing $15 \frac{mile}{hour}$ by .000315 miles ?  Namely, what units are left when you divide $\frac{miles}{hour}$ by miles?

Comment: The units left are _per hour_.

Comment: And I need to magically add the radians unit, correct?   So, the angular speed is $X\frac{radians}{hour}$

Comment: I edited the question to include my result.  Does it look ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with:

$$W = \frac{15 \frac{miles}{hour}}{20 in.}=.75\frac{miles}{hour*in.}(\frac{1 hour}{60 mins})(\frac{1 rev}{2\pi rad})(\frac{12 in}{1 ft})(\frac{5280 ft}{1 mile}) = \frac{(.75)(12)(5280)}{(60)(2\pi)} \frac{revs}{mins}=126 \frac{revs}{mins}$$